# Problem with proving the minimum modulus principle

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

I am working on proving the minimum modulus principle, and I have it nearly down, the last thing that I need to show is that a polynomial $p(z)=a_o+a_1z+......a_nz^n$ has at least one local minimum point. After I have this, with the fact that $p(z)$ is nonconstant and analytic, I have that if $a$ was the minimum point, that $p(a)=0$ which is my contradiction, but how to I show that $p$ has at least one local minimum point? I was thinking that the extreme value theorem could be used here as long as $p(z) \in [a,b]$ z. But I think this approach may not be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to prove more than that. If $|z|$ is large enough, then $\bigl|P(z)\bigr|>\bigl|P(0)\bigr|$. To be more precise, there is some $M>0$ such that $|z|\geqslant M\implies\bigl|P(z)\bigr|>\bigl|P(0)\bigr|$. Now, the closed disk $\overline{D_M(0)}$ is compact, and therefore, there is some $z_0\in\overline{D_M(0)}$ such that$$\left(\forall z\in\overline{D_M(0)}\right):\bigl|P(z_0)\bigr|\leqslant\bigl|P(z)\bigr|.$$In particular, $\bigl|P(z_0)\bigr|\leqslant\bigl|P(0)\bigr|<\bigl|P(0)\bigr|+1$. This proves that, if $|z|\geqslant M$, you also have $\bigl|P(z_0)\bigr|\leqslant\bigl|P(z)\bigr|$, and therefore $|P|$ attains an *absolute* minimum at $z_0$.